# My Broadcast receiver get execute even if my application is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

My broadcast receiver is Still getting execute even if My application is not working.

as an example I am using android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL to check outgoing call and than i stop music and push notification .. 
but even i close my app and kill all task and after if i call than i get notification of my app..
So how do i manage to work my broadcast when i am using my app.
I have crated Service to play music and 2 broadcast receiver file for incoming and outgoing.
Help to solve this problem.

Also How can i destroy my app with service running behind If user press exit button.
**Update I made edited it and its working now fine..thank you so much you all

here is my code

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
          </activity>

    <receiver android:name="OutgoingCallInterceptor">                          
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">                                  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />  
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="IncomingCallInterceptor">                          
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">                                  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />  
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Update**
as you all suggest me i have made receiver into main class file and register it from there but it wont work

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
RemoteViews layout;
int SDK_INT;
 BroadcastReceiver br;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY");
     this.registerReceiver(br, filter);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        System.out.println(SDK_INT);
        Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop); 
        start.setOnClickListener(startListener);
        stop.setOnClickListener(stopListener);
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {  
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (intent.getAction().equals(android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)) {
context.stopService(new Intent(context, myPlayService.class));
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Headphones disconnected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
            }  }
        };

@Override   
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(br);
}
```

Comment: here you have registered the reciver in manifest instead register your reciver inside an activity and un register it on destroy or on pause

Comment: @iccthedral for that too he will have to register the receiver and un register it from some activity itself and again define that the receiver is not enabled by default in the manifest (doesn't it make it more complicated)

Comment: How can i achieve that by coding..can you please explain me in detail or any sample example of that?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an example: how a broadcast reciver can be registered and un registered change as per your need "i hope the code is self explanatory"

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver xyz= new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
//ur reciver
 }
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);//ur action
this.registerReceiver(xyz, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
unregisterReceiver(xyz);
 }
```

Comment: in this case you don't need to register the receiver in your manifest you can un register  @ on pause and register in onresume etc ass per your need (use the lifecycle in the best suited way for your app)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare unregisterReceiver() in onResume() or in onpause() methods. 
This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### First:

use `unregisterReceiver()` in onPause() and re-register in onStart().

It's always better to have locally registering the receiver if you want to provide the functionality only when your app is up.

### Second:

Use service after binding it and don't call `unBind` while exiting the app will keep your service alive even after your app is down. I guess you are starting the service locally. Start service by binding it.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have not bind the service with main class. I just use this to start my service to play audio streaming 
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,myPlayService.class));
 and in service my onbind () return null and in oncreate i write code for media-player and in onDestroy() i just stop media-player object mp.stop and mp.release...should i need to bind my service with main class?.. i am new to android development so i don't have much knowledge about it

Comment: Yup then my guessing is correct. The way you are starting your service is the process of starting the service locally by calling startService(intent). Please use bindService(). here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). Just use it.