# Setting the speaker on doesn't always work

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, android-audiomanager

I'm making an app that the user can call his favorite contacts through my app. 
When the call starts the speaker turns on. 
In order to make a call im using this Intent.

```
               Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: "+contactnum.get(0)));
                startActivity(callIntent);
```

And when there's an out going call there's an Intent that starts a BroadcastReceiver

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcast">
    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>



public class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
                if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                }
                else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){

                    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                }
                else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){

                    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };
        TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if(mgr != null){
            mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the onReceive is turning the speaker on when needed.

The problem is that the speaker doesn't always turn on, but only on the first call that the user makes. The weird part is that if the user makes a call while the app is running but not through my app it works properly, the speaker turns on every time.
What can cause such a thing?

And something else, even when the app is not running it's like that the intent that starts the receiver keeps working, so when I make calls or get calls it turns the speaker although the app is not even running.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i got it to work.

I've changed the Intent Filter so it has only one action

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
```

and when the TelephonyManager is in Offhook state I  set the audioManager mode

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

right before setting the speaker on, and it works.

Update

So still it was working when the app wasn't running, but then I found this question [My Broadcast receiver get execute even if my application is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423271/my-broadcast-receiver-get-execute-even-if-my-application-is-not-working)
and I realized that i should register the receiver in my main activity and unregister it in the activity's onDestroy.